# Text beside image moving when resized

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image, display

I'm working on a website and I'm trying to list some text with image about it, but when the win is resized the text move behind image..
I look for answers on related topics, try all solutions but nothing to do.

[no-resized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wC61f.png)

[resized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rj6ng.png)

sorry for the paint draft,
but we can see a container div, div for img (to manage display) and anothe div for the text

**CSS:**

```
#listWithImg .img {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    margin: 10px;
}
#listWithImg ul {
    width:100%;
    padding-bottom: 0px !important;
    padding-top: 0px !important;
    margin-top:0px !important;
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}
#listWithImg .description {
    float:right;
    display: inline-block;
}
#listWithImg .line {
    display: inline-block;
}

<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="line">
            <div class="img">
                <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-380" src="linkImg" alt="img.png" width="32" height="32" />
            </div>
            <div class="description">
                <h6>Text-Small-Title</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
...
```

Thanks all for help !

Comment: There are many different approaches to 'fixing' this.  The reason this is happening is because there is not enough window space to allow the image and the text to fit side-by-side.  When you resize the window many different things could happen to allow for space.  Please specify what you would like to happen or else you will receive many different 'solutions' that may not actually provide the desired result.  (i.e. The text on the right could wrap within a div that remains to the right of the image, the image could resize to allow space for the text, both could resize, font could resize, etc.)

Comment: If you want so that text is right top and image is left top, one way is to set `min-width` for to the container in which both are placed.

Comment: yes I see, as you know I just want the text beside image (for a list), if the win format is smartphone it will be an image and a paragraph next to.

Comment: If used on smartphone, text should be below the image, that would be much better. At least, I have seen like that almost everywhere.

Comment: Maybe because it's most easier to do, I assume

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ok!
if you want children "img" and "text" side by side you need to change display of parent:

.line {display: flex;}

You can play with children's display 
CSS

```
.img {
   flex-direction: row;
}

.text {
   flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
...
```

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

```
.img{float:left;}
```

That's all.
Demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/y48gnhcm/

Comment: Yes but you have too much css on other elements. See my jsfiddle.

Comment: @DeepestGray I think he ment `#listWithImg .description` float left.

Comment: I know, there's too much css, but same problem with your jsfiddle, when I resize the win' the text goes below image.